# Touch screen Android - red square is displayed, everywhere in the app

Tags: android, touch, screen

I have an issue that happened, my guess, after updating Android Studio to 3.3.2.
The touches are recorded on the screen as red squares, no matter where I am in the app. Tested on real devices, same thing.

I don't know where to start debugging.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IhJq.png)

[red squares as views in layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZh1R.png)

Comment: strange issue .  have you code anything related to touch ?

Comment: No, I only changed something related to local room db. But it's strange because it's happens anywhere in the app, and not in a single activity.

Comment: From what I see in the layout inspector tools, those red squares are in fact views added to the layout.

Comment: can you remove that views ?